# Cannot execute mklink (in an attempt to relocate user files)

Tags: windows-7

I've freshly installed Windows 7 on a slim SSD drive (25 GB), meant just for booting the o.s.

I'm trying now to relocate the user files to a different drive. Lots of sweat and no luck, whatsoever..

I'm following the instructions found on the Net about making a hard link.

I'm using an administrator acount. When trying to run "mklink" Windows says mklink is not found.

When starting cmd and executing the command:
mklink C:\Users\SomeUser G:\Users\SomeUser /J

Widows says I don't have access..

I'd appreciate any help,
thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the command prompt is elevated. An indicator for this is that it says "Administrator:" in its title. You can can elevate a cmd by right clicking it and selecting Run as Administrator or hold down Ctrl+Shift while clicking on cmd.

The next thing you want to do is create a symbolic link (softlink) rather than a Junction. This only works when the source directory doesn't exist because the command will create it.

`mklink /D C:\Users\<UserFolder that doesn't exist> G:\Users\<Folder to redirect to>`
`mklink C:\Users\SomeUser G:\Users\SomeUser` will create the folder SomeUser in C:\users\ that actually redirects all access to G:\users\SomeUser.

Here's the output from my cmd with a pseudo C:\ and G:\ drive:

```
C:\temp>mklink /D C:\C-Drive\Users\SomeUser C:\G-Drive\Users\SomeUser
symbolic link created for C:\C-Drive\Users\SomeUser <<===>> C:\G-Drive\Users\SomeUser

C:\temp>dir C:\C-Drive\Users\

 Directory of C:\C-Drive\Users

04.08.2013  02:34    <DIR>          .
04.08.2013  02:34    <DIR>          ..
04.08.2013  02:34    <SYMLINKD>     SomeUser [C:\G-Drive\Users\SomeUser]
```

Comment: Indeed, Ctrl+Shift on cmd worked.. how is one to know this? but anyway.. now, how can I ever get to delete the original folders (in order to create a link of the same name) when I'm loged in as one of the users? It won't work with Users and it won't work with ProgramDate either. I have tried it (and got myself into lots of trouble)..

Comment: I'd say create a new user with admin privileges and log in with that account. Then move the user profile folder of your current user account to the G:\ Drive and create the symbolic link in an elevated command prompt. Then switch to your user account and see if the redirection works.